# Decrypt a database with Qt 6 and save it as an unencrypted file

Tags: database, encryption, qt6, qsqldatabase

I am using Qt 6, and I know that a DB file is encrypted with `PRAGMA hexkey='123'`, and can be decrypted by QSqlDataBase and then queried in memory.

However, I can't save it as an unencrypted DB file, how can I do that?

I tried `QSqlQuery.exec("PRAGMA hexkey='123'")`, and this is querying in memory, but the files are still encrypted.

Comment: Seems you are using the sqlcrypt to encrypt data in the DB. The whole purpose is to keep the encryted data and being able to query. The PRAGMA sets the key in the session, not decrypting files. Technically you could dump the DB content to another not encrypted database